# Display flex not working even after adding display webkits in both Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

I am trying to make a simple navigation bar in HTML/CSS and I am following a youtube tutorial. I followed the exact steps but for some reason, the display flex is not working.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>IEEE GRIET SB</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav_links">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Societies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Exe - Com</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pragnya</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Laurels</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;600&display=swap');

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li,a{
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:center;
    padding: 30px 10%;
}
```

[This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2BBk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You are using `flex` on the `header`, which is having only one child i.e. `nav`.

Either use `display flex` on the `ul`

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;600&display=swap');

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li,a{
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:center;
}

header{
    padding: 30px 10%;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/qBaLday

---

or use `display inline` on the `li`.

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;600&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li,
a {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
}

header {
  padding: 30px 10%;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/VwKqLaq

Comment: Thank you! In the youtube tutorial, he applied the flexbox to the header. It is working now.